# Matching the verb to be with any words after it followed with to

Tags: regex, boost

I want to match the different forms of the verb *to be* then followed by words without *ing* ending, then followed by *to*.

I have the regex like this:

```
\b(is|it's|are|been|was|were|am|'m)(.*(?!ing\s))\bto\b‌
```

However, when using it with

```
Peppa and George love jumping in muddy puddles.
```

The "jumping in" still could be matched, how to modify the expression?

Comment: Why not just use [`\bjump in\b`](https://regex101.com/r/U0un0e/2)? Do you want to match `jump in` as a whole word? Or just `in` after `jump` and whitespace(s)? Or `in` if not preceded with `ing` + whitespace? [`(?<!ing\s)\bin\b`](https://regex101.com/r/U0un0e/4)? Also, what is the regex library/programming language?

Comment: Try this regex (pcre-php) `.*\b(jump(?!ing))\b.*`. I've made it with this site: https://regex101.com/

Comment: thanks for replying, actually, I want to match the different forms of the verb "be",'\b(is|it's|are|been|was|were|am|'m)(.*(?!ing\s))\bto\b' , then followed by words without "ing" ending, then followed by "to"

Comment: @XiaoChunChen Then why your question is that unclear? Please re-formulate it.

Comment: sorry for the horrible format, because I don't how to use it properly.

Comment: e.g. I want to match phrases like "are so happy to", be + adj + to, and exclude the be + verb+ing to.

Comment: Try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/EnXprE/1).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex to match `be + space-separated word(s) + to` while excluding `be + verb-ing + to`:

```
(?:\b(?:is|it's|are|been|was|were|am)|(?:\B'm))(?:\s+\w++(?<!ing))*\s+to\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yPQXAm/2)

**Details**

- `(?:` - an alternation group:

  - `\b(?:is|it's|are|been|was|were|am)` - a whole word from the list
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:\B'm)` - `'m` not preceded with any word char
- `)` - end of the group
- `(?:\s+\w++(?<!ing))*` - 0+ sequences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\w++(?<!ing)` - a word not ending with `ing`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `to\b` - a whole word `to` (`\b` is a word boundary)

Note that a single `\b` at the start won't let you match `'m` as `'` is not a word char. You may replace the first `(?:\b(?:is|it's|are|been|was|were|am)|(?:\B'm))` part with `(?<!\w)(?:is|it's|are|been|was|were|am|'m)`, or, if you want to match them only if not preceded with whitespace, `(?<!\S)(?:is|it's|are|been|was|were|am|'m)`. Or, `(?<![^\W\d_])(?:is|it's|are|been|was|were|am|'m)` (if not preceded with a letter).

Comment: thanks, and after I added some" ing " and " to" to the text, it failed. https://regex101.com/r/yPQXAm/1,